# JSON parse returns NSDicationary with empty values

Tags: ios, json

I'm trying to transform a very simple JSON in to a NSDicationary to then populate my CoreData model with the retrieved data, the problem is after I get my json from the server and try to parse it to a NSDicationary my dictionary just show I have 811 values inside but they all are empry values.

[image: NSDictionary]

I have printed my json (NSData) and all the content is there and my error var is null after this point.

This is the piece of code I use to do the parse:

```
 [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error]
```

And here is an example of my JSON:

```
[
    {
        "product": "A",
        "name": "B"
    },
    {
        "product": "B",
        "name": "A"
    }
]
```

If I print the data using the code below, the result is exactly the same I get from my server:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

After clicking in the "I" (information) icon I got that:

> Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid
>   ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector. The process has been
>   returned to the state before expression evaluation.

But can't understand why...

I have already searched for this on stackoverflow and I didn't find any solution to my problem, maybe I'm searching with the wrongs terms.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid—you need quotation marks around `product` and `name`.

Comment: Sorry was my fault, I just copied from Google Chrome, edited the question to show the right JSON

Comment: What is the result of printing the object you get from NSJSONSerialization? The debugging popover has not always worked for me.

Comment: 2014-06-11 17:07:16.895 TestApp[26990:60b] jsonObject=[{"product":"A","name":"B"},{"product":"B","name":"A"}]

Comment: Did you try `NSLog` the output?

Comment: In my other comment I just posted the NSLog from my second parse (to NSString), you mean to log the first serialization code?

Comment: may want to try setting your options to kNilOptions

Comment: Almost the same thing, but this time without the brackets and don't know why but the "name" tag is printed without the quotation mark: 2014-06-11 17:19:56.159 TestApp[27043:60b] (
        {
        "product" = "A";
        name = "B";
    },
        {
        "product" = "B";
        name = "A";
    })

Comment: That sound's very strange to me but I have achieved what I needed just  parsing the data to NSString and then again to NSData :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are parsing your JSON into an `NSDictionary` but the top-level data structure of your JSON is an array. Parse your JSON into an `NSArray`; each element of this array will be an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I already tryed that, I just got the same result but with a empty NSArray, but I have only changed my "results" var to type NSArray. I need to change the way I do the parse?

Comment: Can't understand why but the first time I tested this I got the same error, after testing a bunch of times this was the solution...